# VkPipelineInfoEXT does not exist

Tags: c++, cmake, vulkan

I was recently following a tutorial for Vulkan called vkguide.dev.

I was on Chapter 1 part 2 called Vulkan Intialization Code(https://vkguide.dev/docs/chapter-1/vulkan_init_code/), this tutorial uses a bootstrap library to intialize Vulkan(https://github.com/charles-lunarg/vk-bootstrap/).

However when I use the library
in the VKBootstrapDispatch.h file, on line 2318 clang/cmake are complaining about VkPipelineInfoEXT not being a valid type. It suggests VkPipelineInfoKHR however when I switch the type, my code says that there are undefined symbols for arm64 and all of these functions relate to the library.

I couldn't find anything about this online, so it would be great if you could help. I'll attach some screenshots.

The errors are:

VkPipelineInfoEXT does not exist
VkPipelineInfoKHR works but then it says vulkan functions are undefined symbols.

This is what is says when I use KHR instead of EXT

```
_vkDestroyDevice", referenced from:
  VulkanEngine::Cleanup() in VkEngine.cpp.o

"_vkDestroyImageView", referenced from:
      VulkanEngine::Cleanup() in VkEngine.cpp.o

  "_vkDestroyInstance", referenced from:
  VulkanEngine::Cleanup() in VkEngine.cpp.o

  "_vkDestroySurfaceKHR", referenced from:
  VulkanEngine::Cleanup() in VkEngine.cpp.o

  "_vkDestroySwapchainKHR", referenced from:
  VulkanEngine::Cleanup() in VkEngine.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)                               CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/debu

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17 -O3")

project(Vulkan-Raytracing-Project)

add_executable(Vulkan-Raytracing
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/VkEngine.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/vkbootstrap/VkBootstrap.cpp
)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Found SDL2")
message(STATUS "Found Vulkan")
# target_link_libraries(Vulkan-Raytracing PUBLIC SDL2         ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})

target_link_libraries(Vulkan-Raytracing ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}     $    {VULKAN_LIBRARIES})

# target_link_directories(Vulkan-Raytracing PUBLIC     "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/SDL")
# target_link_libraries(Vulkan-Raytracing PUBLIC libSDL2maind.a)

# target_link_libraries(Vulkan-Raytracing         ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/SDL/libSDL2maind.a)

target_include_directories(Vulkan-Raytracing PRIVATE
    ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src"
    "/Users/nick/VulkanSDK/1.3.211.0/macOS/include"
)
```

[image: Original Issue]

[image: Changes]

[image: Cmake]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but it turns out that Vulkan was not getting linked properly, and I included the .dylib that came with the sdk and the build worked.